# How to prevent JComboBox removeAllItems from triggering action Listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a `JComboBox` that I would like to update a `SouthPanel` when the `selectedItem` is changed. This works fine, but if I update the panel the `JComboBox` is contained in, it must `removeAllItems()` and add items back, as the items may have changed causing the panel update. I have a variable storing the index of the combo box so it can set the same index after the update.

The issue is, when the `removeAllItems()` is run, it triggers the `ActionListener`, and sets the `selectedIndex` to 1. How can I get around this?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(sequenceComboBox.getSelectedIndex() > -1){
        selectedIndex = sequenceComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
        selected = medb.getContentManager().getSequences().get(sequenceComboBox.getSelectedIndex());
        updateSouth();
        System.out.println("sequence updated to " + selectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about, instead of trying to manipulate the model, replace it with a new one?  You may also need to set up a flag of some kind which can be used to notify the `ActionListener` that a change is occurring and that it should ignore any notifications

Comment: You can always remove all listeners, and reattach them after processing.